# MVC jQuery DatePicker Style

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm currently implementing a MVC  application against a database in which the create form allows me to instert a new register into the db.

I tried to use jQuery DatePicker for showing DateTime fields and get the info.

My problem is that after implement it, css style works perfectly on IE9 but not in Chrome.

In Chrome.... if a do a click on the field and hold the button pressed, datepicker appears with the css theme applied. Once i release the mouse button, css style dissapears. Then, i select a date (on non-styled calendar) and the calendar come back to css applied and is not remembering my choice. Then i need to re-select the date on css-styled calendar.

**\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml** ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">        </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
   @RenderBody()
```

**\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml** ...

```
@model Nullable<DateTime> 

 @{ 
     DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; 
    if (Model != null) 
    { 
      dt  = (System.DateTime) Model; 

    } 
    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", dt.ToShortDateString()), 
     new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  }) 
}
```

**\Views\Agent\Create.cshtml** ...

```
@model Agente.Receipts

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>





@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Receipts</legend>


  <!--  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReceiptId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReceiptId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReceiptId)
    </div> -->

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuantityReceived)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityReceived)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuantityReceived)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReceivedWareHouseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReceivedWareHouseDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReceivedWareHouseDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PONumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PONumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PONumber)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weight)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CommentsReceived)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CommentsReceived)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentsReceived)
    </div>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: As explained in the first post I´ve a problem in Chrome applying CSS style to the DatePicker.

Answer (score 1):

i had quite similar type of problem with jquery-ui datepicker and after some experimentation it worked for me perfectly througout all the browsers.

i guess this would help you. firstly, you don't need to add every single .js file from the [jquery-ui](http://www.jqueryui.com) package. you just need to add jqery-ui.css from this location of your ui-package (themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and a single .js file from this location (ui/jquery-ui.js). it works for every single jquery ui function. including demoes.css or not will not have much effect to datepicker

these are uncompressed version of files, you can refer to minified versions also if you want. i hope it works for you. if not then check weather some other -webkit- type style is conflicting

please mention if this worked for you or not.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply

I tried to replace all jquery-ui headers by

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.css")"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

but still having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry...

Hello, Thanks for your reply

I tried to replace all jquery-ui headers referencing only the .js and .css you told me. Still having the same problem.

tried to add all headers i posted at the beggining of this thread in both files (\Views\Agent\Create.cshtml   and   \Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml ). Now the behavior is working fine in both browsers but css style is missed in Chrome. :(

Comment: okay, are you using latest version of chrome and what style are you giving to datepicker which is not working !

Comment: Yes, Chrome is updated (v. 20.0.1132.57).

I´m trying to apply the default style (I think. I´m newbie with MVC and jQuery)

I´ve uploaded two files in order you can see the results in Chrome (link 1) and IE9 (link 2)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/571/96149724.jpg/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/77098329.jpg/

Thanks in advance